# How to Use Images as Labels in Chart.js with Angular

Tags: angular, chart.js

It seems like you're using Chart.js with Angular and you want to display images instead of the years 2009, 2010, 2011, and 2012. You mentioned that you found something, but it didn't work for you. Could you provide more details about what you tried and any specific issues you encountered? Additionally, sharing some code snippets or examples would be helpful in understanding your problem better. With more information, I'll do my best to assist you.

```html
  <div class="m-6">
    <canvas id="myChart" width="1000" height="500"></canvas>
  </div>
```

```html
new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: ['2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'],
        datasets: [{
          label: 'My First Dataset',
          data: [25, 59, 80, 76],
          fill: false,
          backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)', 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)', 'rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)', 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)'],
          borderColor: ['rgb(255, 99, 132)', 'rgb(255, 159, 64)', 'rgb(255, 205, 86)', 'rgb(75, 192, 192)', 'rgb(54, 162, 235)'],
          borderWidth: 1
        }]
      },
      options: {
        plugins: {
          datalabels: {
            anchor: 'end',
            align  : 'start'
          },
          labels: {
            render: 'image',
            textMargin: 20,
            images: [
              {
                src: 'https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-3-0/48/ic_book_48px-256.png',
                height: 50,
                width: 50
              },
              {
                src: 'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/glypho-free/64/pen-checkbox-256.png',
                height: 25,
                width: 25
              },
              {
                src: 'https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/jumpicon-basic-ui-glyph-1/32/-_Home-House--256.png',
                height: 25,
                width: 25
              },
              {
                src: 'https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-media-vol-3/24/_google_chrome-256.png',
                height: 25,
                width: 25
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82PKd.png)

[image]

Comment: The question description is quite weird, seems like you are guiding someone. Can you please specify what is your issue/problem.